# WordPress CSS Background images not appearing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, image

As said in the title, the background images for my website are not appearing. I am very new to wordpress. I have managed to get normal images in the HTML files to appear `<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/image01.jpg" alt="image description" width="1269" height="441" />`
but for some reason, all the images in my css wont appear. I have done some research while trying to fix this problem, the most common answer is to format the css like so:

```
.logo{
    background:url("/images/logo.png") no-repeat; }
```

but this is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Tom

EDIT:
link to the stye.css in the `header.php` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using this to import your stylesheet:

```
bloginfo('stylesheet_url');
```

it should go in the *href* tag of the *stylesheet link* and the style.css file itself should be in the same directory as index.php

Look at the code to be included in your head tag: http://jsfiddle.net/wpWbN/

Comment: ive updated my original post, i am using the href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )

Comment: all files are located in wp-content/themes/servowatch folder.

Files in that folder are:
index.php,
header.php,
footer.php,
sidebar.php,
images (dir)
js (dir)

Comment: Then try removing the slash at the beginning of the logo background url.

Answer (score 2):

If You are Creating a theme from the scratch means...

*make sure your background image in image folder within your custom theme folder

*then include the image from your custom theme folder

### css file

```
    .header{
         background: url("../custom_theme_folder_name/images/123.png") repeat;
    }
```

Comment: Stylesheet is already in theme folder. do not need to go outside from the custom theme folder.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?

```
.logo{
    background:url("images/logo.png");
}
```

Comment: do you have style on root folder of the theme? or in subfolder?

Comment: root folder. images are in the images folder and thats all

Comment: url("images/logo.png"); use this method for the style. and check your header is threre stylesheet url is perfect or not.

Comment: this worked for me, since the styles.css was directly in the theme folder

Answer (score 1):

In my case my code is like the next line

```
background: url("assets/images/icon.png");
```

my folders are

> `wp-content\themes\theme-name\assets\images`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the adress in your source attribute is not starting where you think it is (meaning you probably don't start from the root node). try this:

```
.logo{
    background:url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat; }
```

or this

```
.logo{
    background:url("../../images/logo.png") no-repeat; }
```